# Vuex state change not updating Vuetify table

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

At a high level, a parent vue contains a table of records and a modal to add a new record. 
The modal emits a call back to the parent which calls a mapped action with the new record. The action posts the new record, and commits the newRecord mutation. The newRecord mutation adds the new record to the state records array.

From what I have read, you must update a state array in a certain way for reaction, which I've done. However I am still not seeing the table update.

**Parent vue**

```
<v-data-table 
      :headers="headers" 
      :items="allRecords" 
      :items-per-page="5" 
      class="elevation-1">
...
</v-data-table>
...
computed: mapGetters(["allRecords"]),
...
methods: {
...mapActions(["getRecords", "addRecord"]),
...
created() {
    this.getRecordss();
}
```

**Records module***

```
import axios from 'axios';

const getters = {
    allRecords: state => state.records
}

const state = {
    records: []
}

const actions = {
    async getRecords({commit}){
        const response = await axios.get('/api/records')
        commit('setRecords', response.data)
    },
    async addRecord({ commit }, record) {
        const response = await axios.post('/api/records', record)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        commit('addRecord', response.data)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setRecords: (state, records) => (state.records = records),
    addRecord: (state, record) => ([...state.records, record])
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Everything works with the post, and refreshing the page shows the new record, but it is not reactively updated.

Comment: move `this.getRecordss();` to `mounted`

Comment: This results in the same behavior, table is not updating unless I refresh.

Comment: your `getRecords` is async, did you await for response?

Comment: I don't understand. The addUser action uses async/await. Should this be changed to synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome Vue debugging plugin, I found that the above mutation wasn't actually adding the new record to the stores array. Modifying the addRecord mutation below corrected the issue. Apparently the spread operator was being used incorrectly.

```
addRecord: (state, record) => ([...state.records, record])
```

to

```
addUser(state, user){
    state.users.push(user);
}
```